# scss prepending parent selector

Tags: css, sass

I have a project where legacy code has classes like

`promo` `game-promo`

I've got the chance to clean up the css by changing to scss but the issue I'm trying to cover is I'd like to nest `promo` and have `game-` prepend the parent.

```
.promo {
  display: flex;
  game-& {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

I'd have liked the above to work but it doesn't and wondering if anyone has come across any ways of achieving what I'm after?

Comment: You forgot the class indicator: `.`.  Have you tried `.game-& { ...`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle that gives me `.game- .promo`  instead of `.game-promo`

Comment: no, i think you cannot

Answer (score 0):

```
.game-promo {
  color: black;
  @at-root .promo {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

It seems its not possible so after re-jigging the code I have now got this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying. The "&" is used to get the current selector, in your case : `game-.promo` or `.game-.promo` if you add the class selector but it can't work.

In your case, you can do :

```
.game-promo {
    color: black;
    .promo {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Or rename your classes name : (I give an example with inverting the logic of your names)

- Parent with ".promo"
- Child with ".promo-game"

So you could do :

```
.promo {
    //properties
    &-game {
        //properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not very pretty ([code on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abrnhf87/12/)):

```css
/** see https://gist.github.com/Bamieh/912a6f0b63cbb53f3ad0bd8df7171c6a */
@function parse-dotless($class) {
  $this: quote($class);
  @return if(str-slice($this, 0, 1) == ".", str-slice($this, 2, str-length($this)), $this);
}

.promo {
  color:yellow;
  @at-root .game-#{parse-dotless(&)} {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="promo">Hello</span>
<span class="game-promo">World</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do exactly what your snippet states using only the `&` feature. Instead you could build modifier classes like this:

```
.btn {
  &-primary {}
  &-secondary {}
}
```

Which is translated to:

```
.btn-primary {}
.btn-secondary {}
```

In your code example, you can invert the rule names:

```
.promo {
  display: flex;

  &-game {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Read more about the [sass-ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)